# Best approach to achieve this grid layout on iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

A question for the UICollectionView experts.

Imagine a collection view that looks like a table view (full width cells), and when you tap on one of them, new cells are inserted underneath that cell that are square cells, say half the width of the collection view, in 2 columns. Tapping the header again would appear to collapse the section.

Keeping in mind that I’m trying to use UICollectionViewFlowLayout instead of a custom UICollectionView.

Would you:
A) implement the tableview style cells as collection view supplementary views (headers), with a gesture recogniser that inserts the square cells?; or
B) implement the tableview style cells as one cell type, and the square cells as another cell type?; or
C) something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would go with option A. In the situation you're describing the full width item is really a section header that's function is to show/hide it's sections's cells.

From a data structure standpoint this is much easier to maintain with this approach. It can be handled with an array of arrays.

If they were all cells it would most likely be one large array, and would be more difficult to make the distinction between a full width cell and the half width cells.